# Sed extract link from html page

Tags: shell, sed

I'm trying to write a module for uploading with **plowshare** but I have problem with parsing from upload page.

I need to extract upload_url

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  upload_url: "http://s73.domain.com/?action=uploadfiles&user_id=TVRnN21ESX2c&secret_code=f4r6w35q639ih7oi62u674ae91453697", // Relative to the SWF file (or you can use absolute paths)
```

After I login, I load page for upload and then I need to extract upload_url

I try with:

```
'upload_url:' '"\([[:digit:]]|http[:]//[^ ])*'
```

but I get this error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 60: Unmatched ( or \(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sed:**

```
sed -nE 's/.*upload_url: "([^"]+).*/\1/p' filename
```

Output:

```
http://s73.domain.com/?action=uploadfiles&user_id=TVRnN21ESX2c&secret_code=f4r6w35q639ih7oi62u674ae91453697
```

**grep:**

```
grep -oP 'upload_url: "\K[^"]+' filename
```

**awk:**

```
awk -F "\"" '/upload_url/ {print $2}' filename
```